Assert.Throws only partial covered in Visual Studio Enterprize and Azure Devops
I have the problem that all Assert.Throws in my code are only shown as partial covered.
Given the following code the coverage is not 100% as expected, it is instead 89%.
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Test;

[TestFixture]
public class Test1
{
    [Test]
    public void throwsException()
    {
        Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => TestMethod());
    }

    private static void TestMethod()
    {
        throw new Exception("exception");
    }
}

Showing the code coverage colored shows that the lamba expression is only partial covered.
Code coverage
What can I do to get the coverage to 100%?

Remove unnecessary lambda.
public void throwsException()
{
    Assert.Throws<Exception>(TestMethod);
}


For that version, yes. But if I have a parameter for the method throwsException then the lambda is necessary.

ExcludeFromCodeCoverage is an option. Assert.Throws<Exception>([ExcludeFromCodeCoverage] () => TestMethod());
